# Does "a couple of" always mean exactly two?

Tags: meaning

As in the title. Does the expression *a couple of* always have to mean exactly two (like *a pair of*) or can it mean more (things/objects)? I know *a couple*, at least in one of its meanings, means a pair (like *the happy couple*) but as an amount specifier does it also **always** mean exactly two?

Comment: No; it is used loosely to mean *approximately* two.

Comment: It does mean exactly two, for me, but for my wife, it means a small number, around two.

Answer (score 3):

Formally: Yes. It refers to two items *of a type*. In that sense, not only does it always mean two, but the *type* of those two items must always be the same.

eg.

A couple *of people*, A couple *of fruits*.

However, when used informally; it can refer to any indefinite small number.

**That said,** as your question is referring more closely to *meaning* as opposed to definition, I would be inclined to accept the more loose association of the word as being to express *a small number of things of quantity unknown.*